# add data to array delete other content

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

i´m traying to add element into array without delete other content, it´s very trivial... `Array.push()`

my problem it´s i´m using `ref([])` and i´m reading that i can use `ref.value.push = newItem`

but my problem it´s that override my previous content... i need to do that user select checkbox with information, and this information be added to my table. To build this, i´m doing:

```
<input type="checkbox" :id="item.id" :name="item.name" :data-category="item.category.name" style="font-size: 0.6em; transform: scale(1.6);" @change="addToCart($event)"/>
```

and my function `addToCart()`:

```
const addItemCart = ref([])
    const addToCart = (event) => {
        let itemId = event.target.id
        let itemName = event.target.name
        let category = event.target.getAttribute("data-category")

        var newItem = new Array();
        newItem = [{ id: itemId, name: itemName, category: category }];
             
        addItemCart.value = newItem
    }
```

i trayed with:

```
const addItemCart = ref([])
    const addToCart = (event) => {
        let itemId = event.target.id
        let itemName = event.target.name
        let category = event.target.getAttribute("data-category")

        var newItem = new Array();
        newItem = [{ id: itemId, name: itemName, category: category }];
             
        addItemCart.value.push = newItem
        console.log(addItemCart.value)
    }
```

This return:

```
Proxy(Array) {push: Array(1)}

[[Handler]]:Object
[[Target]]: Array(0)
push: Array(1)
0: {id: '96', name: 'DESINCRUSTADOR DCALUXE - HIDROCAL ELECTRONICO', category: 'ARTICULOS B'}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
app.js:20948 

Proxy(Array) {push: Array(1)}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(0)
push: Array(1)
0: {id: '281', name: 'DCALUXE PRO 2.0 DESINCRUSTADOR ELECTRONICO', category: 'ARTICULOS B'}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

Not push data in my array and i can´t show my data in my table, i have this code to do loop:

```
<tr v-for="item in addItemCart" :key="item">
    <td>{{ item }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.category }}</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" @click="removeItem($event)"></i></td>
</tr>
```

My question it´s, how i can to do add items in my array bu not deleted my other content.

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Comment: `addItemCart.value.push = newItem` That's not how you `push` an item into an array...

Comment: you're also creating a variable `newItem` but as an array with one object in it. Seems like it would probably help if you created `newItem` as a single instance of that object. Something like `newItem = { id: itemId, name: itemName, category: category };`

Comment: @Cerbrus i have a ref([]) in ```vueJS``` and i read that i can use this

Comment: @Portal thanks for your response i´m trying your commet but i have same problem

Comment: `.push` is a function: `myArray.push(anItem)`.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, but this it´s a vue ```ref()```

Comment: @Cerbrus if i do ```addItemCart.push = { id: itemId, name: itemName, category: category }``` i have empty array... To set value in vue ref it´s necesary ```addItemCart.value```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using push as a function, and passing the new object to push as a parameter:

```js
const addItemCart = ref([])
const addToCart = (event) => {
    let itemId = event.target.id
    let itemName = event.target.name
    let category = event.target.getAttribute("data-category")
          
    addItemCart.value.push({ id: itemId, name: itemName, category: category })
    //here we push the new item as an object into `addItemCart.value`
}
```